# Computing the invariant factors of a sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

Let `M` be a sparse $n\times m$ integral matrix, where $nm$ is very large. The goal is to compute its [invariant factors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvariantFactor.html). The naïve approach `Diagonal[SmithDecomposition[M][[2]]]` is presumably not ideal, as it is computing more information than what I acctually need. Is there a better approach?

Note: I only care about the non-zero factors; does this simplify the problem?